# Chrome extensions: import local Javascript into popup.html

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I know you can use the manifest for contentscripts.. but is there any way I can import local javascript files into popup.html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your popup.html is an extension page, then it is a normal HTML page. You can add an import in there.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="local_javascript.js"></script>
```

Hope that helped!

Comment: Oh, so I can just import like I would with a website?!

Comment: Extensions are like websites with a set of extra API's :) A popup is a normal html page that gets shown once you click that browser action, and disposes once that popup closes.